# How to hit the database on the function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a quesion can I hit the database on my view?

I have function like this..

```
  function ShowHIPAATab(url) {

            if ($("#BxFlag").val() == "1") {
                $("#bv-1").attr('src', url);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

on this funcation I need to hit the database to get the BXFlag value.how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "hit the database"? Where is your Javascript connecting to your server?

Comment: @you can make a clal to some page .php , .aspx through ajax and it can interact with databases...

Comment: this is not in the least bit clear. BxFlag would be an element on your page. Why and where are you "hitting the database"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this being javascript it is running in the browser not the server, so you don't have direct access to the database.  Depending on your situation there a couple ways you can get this value:

- If the value is known at the time that you render the page then you can set a javascript variable with the value in your view. This has the advantage of being simple and not requiring an additional call to the server.
- If the value can not be known until after you render, or if it can change during the lifetime of the page then use jquery AJAX as gov points out.

Answer (score 3):

use jquerys ajax

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```